# Pre-Build event exiting with code -1 in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, batch-file, antlr, pre-build-event

I have a simple batch script running the command line in the pre-build event is just

`C:\path\to\batch\script\PreBuildGenANTLR.bat`

The batch script contains

`@echo off
pushd ..\..\Parser
java -jar ..\ANTLR\antlr-3.5-complete.jar -o .ANTLR ExprCppTree.g
popd`

I've tried exit 0 exit \b 0 SET ERRORLEVEL = 0 but it seems like no matter what I do the script runs but the build stops and errors out with error MSB3073 exited with code -1. I've tried a bunch of other things to make this script return zero including the steps outlined at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/08/08/691849.aspx . Still nothing. The script runs with a bunch of warnings but no errors. It does what it's supposed to do but still the build stops and exits with code -1. What in the heck am I doing wrong? How can I make it return zero and continue the build?

Comment: Are you **`call`** ing the batch script from the pre-build event?  `call C:\path\PreBuildGenANTLR.bat` Is the java command returning the -1 exit code?  Might try catching the exit code.  `java -jar ..\ANTLR\antlr-3.5-complete.jar -o .ANTLR ExprCppTree.g || verify >nul`  Also at the end of the script use `exit /b 0`.

Comment: No. Like I said the script is running and doing everything properly when I run it from cmd but for some reason when I put it into vsStudio it returns -1

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010, all you need to do is use the NuGet Package Manager to install the [Antlr3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr3) package (make sure the **Id** listed for the package is *exactly* **Antlr3**). With the package installed, to compile a grammar you just need to select the **.g** or **.g3** file(s) in your project and set the **Build Action** property to `Antlr3`.